# String manipulation based on lists

Tags: python, string, loops

Hello I need to write a function that will automatically make a specific string

For example I have a List of elements:

```
tab = [12, 23, 13, 4, 2]
```

I want the function to take each element and add it to a string like so:

string:

> 12 + 23x + 13x^2 + 4x^3 + 2x^4

Basically, rewrite 1st element then add `'x'` to the 2nd and every other but every element after 2nd must be raised to the power (starting with 2 on the third element and increasing by 1 for each next element)

The list can be infinitely long and it can contain floats so the function has to be universal

I tried this:

```
tab = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

string = ""
num = 0
for x in tab:

    if num < 1:
        string = string + str(x) + ' ' + '+' + ' '
    elif num < 2:
        string = string + str(x) + 'x' + ' ' + '+' + ' '
    else:
        string = string + str(x) + 'x' + f'^{num}' + '+' + ' '
    num = num + 1

print(string)
```

output:

```
'1 + 2x + 3x^2+ 4x^3+ 5x^4+ 6x^5+ 7x^6+ 8x^7+ 9x^8+ 10x^9+'
```

Comment: What code have you got yourself already?

Comment: Well, I actually almost manager to finish it. It's weird and I don't like it but it almost works. I just need to get rid of the plus sign at the end

Comment: Why don't you show the code you have, and ask the question how to get rid of the plus sign at the start instead?

Comment: Try `string = string.rstrip('+')` at the very end (past your for-loop). `rstrip` stands for right-strip, and will remove the corresponding character from the right side of the string, i.e., remove the plus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the simplest code to do this. Initiate the `output_string` with the first number that is cast to be a string. Then, iterate on other elements of the list and do concatenation of `+x^index` to the `output_string`:

```
tab = [12, 23, 13, 4, 2]
output_string = str(tab[0])
for each_index in range(1, len(tab)):
    output_string += " + " + str(tab[each_index]) + "x^" + str(each_index)
print(output_string)
```

The output:

```
12 + 23x^1 + 13x^2 + 4x^3 + 2x^4
```

Answer (score 1):

in a compact way to *create* the `list`, you could use `enumerate`:

```
tab = [12, 23, 13, 4, 2]
result = []
for index,element in enumerate(tab):
    result.append(str(element)+(f"x^{index}" if index != 0 else ''))
print("list: ",result)
```

output:

```
['12', '23x^1', '13x^2', '4x^3', '2x^4']
```

and then join with the `' + '` string:

```
result = ' + '.join(result)
print("actual string:",result.__repr__())
```

output:

```
list: ['12', '23x^1', '13x^2', '4x^3', '2x^4']
actual string: '12 + 23x^1 + 13x^2 + 4x^3 + 2x^4'
```